# How to define custom path to Interop *.dll

Tags: dll, interop, managed-c++

Well,

I have an **ActiveX (*.ocx) component**, and i use it in a **managed C++/CLI project**: write a managed wrapper around ActiveX component[ *NET has a great **Interop services** : provides me genarated dll so i can easily use it in my managed code*]

The problem is that Visual Studio (2008) automatically copy the **generated Interop *.dll** to the directory **where my *.exe file stay**.But i want put all my genarated Interop *.dll to a folder ...

Suppose My directory structure is so:

**D:\MyProject\Output\MyProject.exe**  //*My mamanged exe*

**D:\MyProject\Output\Interop.XXXLib.1.0.dll** // *Interop *.dll*

I want to put Interop.XXXLib.1.0.dll  into new folder

**D:\MyProject\Output\Interops**

and use it from that directory...How Can i do it?

Best Wishes

PS:

What I found so far was using using codeBase/ probing tags in my app.config file such as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com.asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Interops" />
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But i did not work in C++/CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **fixit...**
Visual studio 2008 C++/CLI automatically create config file with name ***app.config*** . I changed this name with assembly name **MyProject.exe.config** and it works now...There is a **hidden convention** i think  **assembly.dll.config** or **assembly.exe.config** naming pattern which i do not know...